# Edit HTML inside of Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird idea for my project. I simply want to get all the document HTML, put it inside a Jquery object and render the result to `<pre>` on this page. I am not sure if this possible due to the lack of information that I found so I expect to at least see some hints on how to make this.

The thing here is that I know the basics, I need EXACTLY the way of changing the code/text/data INSIDE the Jquery object. Maybe it is possible with regular expressions but I would prefer not to use them at all. I don't know if that's possible to do with string replace function. But that can't be that hard! There should be a way of doing this with some existing Jquery functions. So here is what I have done so far:

```
function getHTML() {
    return "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + $('html')[0].outerHTML;
}

var originalPage = getHTML();
$(".body-block pre code").text(originalPage);
```

I can use `originalPage` now to find some info inside of it:

```
$(originalPage).find("pre code").text();
```

But I can't change any info:

```
$(originalPage).find("pre code").text("New Text!");
$(".body-block pre code").text(originalPage);
```

The code above does nothing for some reason. Any idea why and how can I make changes inside of `originalPage` to the `HTML`?

Just to complete this question here is an example of HTML that I use:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tests</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Tests">
  <meta name="author" content="Telion">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css?v=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css?v=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="body-block">
        <pre><code>Hello World!</code></pre>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clone document -> do operations -> make html out of the clone.

Comment: @René how exactly do I do operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it actually turned out that we can `clone` objects and then do anything we want with them. As @Rene mentioned I googled more about this and made the working example for myself:

```
originalPage = $("html").clone();
$(originalPage).find("pre code").text("New Text!");
```

This question is closed, in two days I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a div with the id of test. You can set the content of this div to an h4 tag with the words hey by using the following Jquery code:

```
$("#test").html(<h4>Hey</h4>)
```

If you would like to append some html to already existing html you can use the following

```
$("#test").append(<h4>Hey</h4>)
```

**The documentation to rid all the HTML in a tag and add new content: http://api.jquery.com/html/**

**The documentation to add HTML content to a tag: 
http://api.jquery.com/append/**

Comment: I know that perfectly already. My problem is to change info not in the DOM but in the Jquery object. So I want to clone all the code, change it invisibly and render changed information, I don't want to change info in code before I clone it.

Comment: Why dont you store the jquery object in a string and perform an operation on the string instead of the object?

Comment: Like `replaceWith`? I need to edit all the text inside `<pre>`. I want to add or remove anything inside of it. I don't think I can do that normally with replace.